# Mesh crotch area deforms really weird when posing - using Auto-Rig Pro for armature

Tags: armature, weight-painting, topology, auto-rig-pro

This model I am using is a model I got off of CGTrader, so I didn't make it, but I've been trying to rig it using Auto-Rig Pro.

It did have an armature with it when I downloaded it but it didn't work as well as I wanted, no issues with the crotch deforming though. I tried Auto-Rig Pro, everything else seems to move just fine but the crotch area deforms in a weird way. I've tried weight painting it and it helps a bit but not all the way.

I also tried to add custom bones by the inner part of the thigh, which seem to work but they didn't move automatically with the rest of armature even when parented (not sure if they even can with Auto-Rig Pro armature).

I also tried changing the location of the bones that Auto-Rig Pro created, it didn't result in anything better.

I was thinking maybe the topology may need to be redone but not sure. If anyone has any ideas or tips on how to fix this so then I know what to do in the future if it happens again, that would be great!

Also I am somewhat new to Blender, still learning it but kinda know my way around a little bit

Here is the model in rest pose and the topology:

[image: Rest pose]

Here is the model with its legs moved and for some reason the crotch pops out like that and even if I weight paint it, it still does this

[image: Legs moved and deformed crotch]

These two weight paint images are the original weight paint done by Auto-Rig Pro that results in the strange deformation. There are two vertex groups that control this part of the leg.

[image: Original weight paint - vertex one]

[image: Original weight paint - vertex two]

When I made changes to the weight paint and the results. Not a perfect weight paint but I was just trying out things to see what would work but no matter what I did the results were about the same

[image: Changed weight paint - vertex one]

[image: Changed weight paint - vertex two]

The results:

[image: Result]

Using Blender 3.2.1

Comment: It looks like the problem is indeed the weight paint. I believe it looks better after you edited the weight painting on the legs. Auto Rig and other automated solutions are not perfect and never were. Most of the time they require additional work to weight painting.

On your last picture you can see that the front of the crotch seems to deform better but a part of the back still stretches. Try and improve the backside of the thighs weight paint and see if that solves the problem.

Comment: @SolomonTheScapegoat sorry for the late reply, i was trying out your suggestion. i think i got it down now, it took awhile messing around with the weight paint. i kept getting random extrusions each time i weight painted and it was always bumpy looking. took awhile to make it smooth and looking nice.  i also ended up noticing that there was a vertex group that i didn't realize was effecting that area to. I think its good now. Thank you for your response!

Comment: In the weight paint menu is the option for smoothing out the current weight paint layer as well as other neat options and shortcuts to manual editing. This can help you to reduce these spikes in topology being moved with the bone in a very quick way. You increase the iterations and it gets super soft and smooth everywhere.

Comment: @SolomonTheScapegoat thank you! i need to go through all the options in that menu and see how they all work because i didn't even notice it was there till now. the smoothing option help a lot.